# ClojureScript without Java

Tags: java, node.js, clojure, clojurescript

Is it possible to compile ClojureScript without Java?

I read the clojurescript [nodejs quickstart](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs) but I see they still use java to compile.

I checked [cljs-bootstrap](https://github.com/swannodette/cljs-bootstrap) but they also depend on java.

Is there any way to just use `npm install` and start using clojurescript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now there is Lumo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lumo-cljs

> Lumo is a standalone ClojureScript environment that runs on Node.js and the V8 JavaScript engine. It starts up instantaneously and has out-of-the-box access to the entire Node.js ecosystem.
>
> Lumo also provides a ClojureScript build API, making it possible to compile ClojureScript projects entirely without the JVM, thanks to the experimental JavaScript version of the Google Closure Compiler.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Until ClojureScript is self-hosted (implemented in ClojureScript rather than Clojure), Java is needed as well as Node/NPM.  However, David Nolen said in [his April 20, 2015 talk at Clojure West](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvF-GZI20L4&index=8&list=PLZdCLR02grLrKAOj8FJ1GGmNM5l7Okz0a), relatively little work remains before the compiler can be bootstrapped in itself.  [The talk may be interesting to watch for other reasons as well.]  So this may change in the not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 3):

As of ClojureScript 1.7 self compilation is now supported, see

[This Post](http://swannodette.github.io/2015/07/29/clojurescript-17/)

To set up

```clj
(ns self-compile.core
  (:require cljs.js))

(set! cljs.js/*eval-fn* cljs.js/js-eval)
(def state (cljs.js/empty-state))

(defn my-compiler [str-to-compile]
  (cljs.js/eval-str state str-to-compile
                  (fn [response]
                    ;evaluated code here
                  ))
```

The initial compilation must be done on the JVM, however once this is done the function my-compiler above will compile strings.  To create a sample project with up to date config use the `lein mies` template

```clj
lein new mies my-project
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get started, can you explain a bit more? It seems to me they are still depending on lein which depends on java... let's say I don't have java installed, can I run clojurescript with just nodejs?

Comment: I believe that you need to invoke the JVM at least once to get started, after that you should be all good with just node.js.

Comment: Orlando William, to try clojurescript on nodejs check out https://github.com/whamtet/dogfort